# What is the difference between =label (equals sign) and [label] (brackets) in ARMv6 assembly?

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm following along with the [Baking Pi](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/os/ok05.html) course from Cambridge University, in which a simple operating system is built in the ARMv6 instruction set, targeting the Raspberry Pi.

We've been using two ways of loading data into registers via the `ldr` instruction so far and I realize now that I'm using them together, I don't fully understand what they both do.

So I've used things like `ldr r0,=0x20200000`, which I actually understood as "read the data stored at the memory location 0x20200000 into register r0.

Then I've used things like:

```
ldr r0,[r1,#4]
```

Which I've understood as being "read the data stored at the memory address pointed to by r1, at an offset of 4 bytes, into register r0".

Then I encounter this:

```
ldr r0,=pattern
ldr r0,[r0]
```

`pattern` here is a `.int` in the `.data` section (a bitmap representing a sequence of on/off states for an LED). I realize upon reading this, that my previous understanding of `=foo` must be wrong, otherwise both of the above instructions would do the same thing.

Is the `=x` syntax basically more like a pointer in C, while the `[x]` syntax is as if the memory that is being pointed to by `x` is actually read?

Let's say `ptr` in the C below is an `int*`, do my comments thinking about equivalent assembly (conceptually, not literally) make any sense?

```
r0 = ptr;     /* equivalent to: ldr r0,=ptr     */
r0 = *ptr;    /* equivalent to: ldr r0,[ptr]    */
r0 = *(ptr+4) /* equivalent to: ldr r0,[ptr,#4] */
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046686/ldr-vs-mov-arm-assembly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9374703/llvm-gcc-assembler-ldr-syntax http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9735169/iphone-assembly-compilation-error-with-ldr-parameters

Comment: Related: [Getting an label address to a register on ARM?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15774581) discusses which ways to do that are *efficient*.

Comment: If anyone's got the rep for a 1-character edit, there's now an https version of the URL in the question.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
ldr r0,=something
...
something:
```

means load the address of the label something into the register r0.  The assembler then adds a word somewhere in reach of the ldr instruction and replaces it with a

```
ldr r0,[pc,#offset]
```

instruction

So this shortcut

```
ldr r0,=0x12345678
```

means load 0x12345678 into r0.

being mostly fixed length instructions, you cant load a full 32 bit immediate into a register in one instruction, it can take a number of instructions to completely load a register with a 32 bit number.  Depends heavily on the number.  For example

```
ldr r0,=0x00010000
```

will get replaced by the gnu assembler with a single instruction mov r0,#0x00010000 if it is an ARM instruction, for a thumb instruction though it may still have to be ldr r0,[pc,#offset]

These ldr rd,=things are a shortcut, pseudo instructions, not real.

```
ldr rd,[rm,#offset]
ldr rd,[rm,rn]
```

are real instructions and mean read from memory at address rm+offset or rm+rn and take the value read and put it in the register rd

the =something is more like &something in C.

```
unsigned int something;
unsigned int r0;
unsigned int r1;

r0 = &something;
r1 = *(unsigned int *)r0;
```

and in assembly

```
something:
    .word 0

ldr r0,=something
ldr r1,[r0]
```

Answer (score 2):

It is worth mentioning that there exist the following alternative approaches for those that want to avoid pseudo instructions / the literal pool for some reason:

- `adr r0, label` (v7 / v8): single instruction, stores the full address of the label into `r0`. Refers to label by relative PC addressing it, see also: [What are the semantics of ADRP and ADRL instructions in ARM assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41906688/what-are-the-semantics-of-adrp-and-adrl-instructions-in-arm-assembly) | [Example with asserts](https://github.com/cirosantilli/arm-assembly-cheat/blob/1de6ce8db935f2b0230b00c50c14a19ddd84eef9/v7/adr.S).

  In ARMv7, it is not possible however to access labels in different sections with `adr`, e.g. `.data` from `.text`, apparently because there is no [relocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322911/what-do-linkers-do/33690144#33690144) that takes care of it. `ldr =` can do this. If you try, GAS fails with:

  ```
   Error: symbol .data is in a different section
  ```

  Cross section access is however possible in ARMv8, and generates a relocation of type `R_AARCH64_ADR_PRE`. [Example](https://github.com/cirosantilli/arm-assembly-cheat/blob/1de6ce8db935f2b0230b00c50c14a19ddd84eef9/v8/adr.S).
- `movw` and `movt` (v7) + GNU GAS [`#:lower`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.19/as/ARM_002dRelocations.html):

  ```
  movw r0, #:lower16:myvar
  movt r0, #:upper16:myvar
  ```

  [Example with asserts](https://github.com/cirosantilli/arm-assembly-cheat/blob/afb01b29e278ea2e9448dfad26f66b17728bf21f/v7/ldr_pseudo.S#L54).

  `movk` + shifts (v8) + GNU GAS :

  ```
  movz x0, #:abs_g2:label     // bits 32-47, overflow check
  movk x0, #:abs_g1_nc:label  // bits 16-31, no overflow check
  movk x0, #:abs_g0_nc:label  // bits  0-15, no overflow check
  ```

  [Example with asserts](https://github.com/cirosantilli/arm-assembly-cheat/blob/afb01b29e278ea2e9448dfad26f66b17728bf21f/v8/movk.S#L16).

Comment: When tuning for some ARM CPUs, e.g. `-mcpu=cortex-a53`, gcc will prefer `movw`/`movt` for getting a static address into a register instead of a load from a PC-relative literal pool.

Comment: @Downvoters: please explain so I can learn and improve info. I never retaliate.