# .word entries in the object file

Tags: arm, disassembly

Using ARM objdump(arm-linux-gnueabihf-objdump), I was checking the object file. The objdump output file contains few entries as shown below.

```
80834400:   80843e53    .word   0x80843e53
80834404:   8084628c    .word   0x8084628c
80834408:   80843e61    .word   0x80843e61
8083440c:   80846290    .word   0x80846290
```

Can you please tell what is the meaning of these entries and its usage.

Comment: Are you asking what the `.word` directive means (unsurprisingly, [as per the documentation, it's a word of arbitrary data](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.25/as/Word.html#Word)), or what these particular values represent? The latter isn't really answerable - I mean, they look like they're probably addresses, but without the context of some code actually making use of them, who knows?

Comment: Thanks for the update.
I am new to assembly. First I am trying to understand what is the meaning of it.

Comment: It seems the constants used in the instruction to store in registers are placed in .word directive. The constant value(CONFIG_SYS_INIT_SP_ADDR) of "ldr sp, =CONFIG_SYS_INIT_SP_ADDR" instruction is placed in .word directive.

Comment: Right, so this would appear to be a [literal pool](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0473l/dom1359731147386.html). I'd suggest taking a at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20071767/3156750) and everything linked from it to help understand what that's about.